# I was trying to print the spiral order matrix as output for a given matrix of numbers, but the output result isn't complete. What is causing this?

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to print the spiral order matrix as output for a given matrix of numbers, all seemed fine until I tried to print the output, the code prints the input till the first spiral loop but stops after printing the second loop for the first step. I am confused, what is my mistake.

edit - the loop has to go clockwise.

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class SpiralArray{

 public static void main (String [] args){

    System.out.println("Enter the size of the array");
    //Dimensions of array
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r = sc.nextInt();
    int c = sc.nextInt();

    int [][] spiral = new int [r][c];
    
    // elements of array
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){

            spiral [i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
     
    
    int row_start = 0;
    int row_end = r-1;
    int column_start = 0;
    int column_end = c-1;
    
    //printing spiral order matrix

    while( row_start <= row_end && column_start <= column_end){

        //1
        for (int col = column_start; col <= column_end; col++){

            System.out.print(spiral[row_start][col] + " ");
            
        } 

        row_start++;
        
        //2
        for (int row = row_start; row <= row_end; row++){

            System.out.print(spiral[row][column_end] + " ");
        }

        column_end--;

        //3
        for (int col = column_end; col >= column_start; col--){

            System.out.print(spiral[row_end][col] + " ");
            
        } 
        row_end--;

        //4
        for (int row = row_end; row >= row_start; row--){

            System.out.print(spiral[row][column_start] + " ");
        }

        column_start++;

        System.out.println();
        
         }

    }
 }
```

Output obtained from the code -

```
  Enter the size of the array       
    3 4
    1 2 3 4
    5 5 6 7
    8 9 10 1 
   
    1 2 3 4 7 1 10 9 8 5 
    5 6 5
```

edit
expected output
1 2 3 4 7 1 10 9 8 5
5 6

Comment: Please provide your question with more details. What is the direction of a "spiral" (*clock-wise/counter clock-wise*)? Starting point - **[0][0]**? What is the **expected** output?

Comment: Why the expected sequence `1 2 3 4 7 1 10 9 8 5 5 6 10 9` ends with `10 9`. I thought it'll stop at `6`, what is the rule for that?

Comment: The rule is that the spiral has to be complete, all the elements of the array should be covered by the spiral if it stops at just 6 the spiral isn't complete.

Comment: `all the elements of the array should be covered` - `10` and `9` are already covered `... 1 10 9 8 ...`, and then you are going to visit these elements a second time, why? Why you are calling this shape spiral when it goes from the edge to the center and then returns to the edge? You definitely have to give a more detailed explanation on that point.

Comment: That is the definition of a **spiral** - a curve on a plane that winds around a fixed center point at a continuously increasing or decreasing distance from the point ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral )

Answer (score 0):

well this is the code that i wrote by myself i think there are some bad coding here and there but works fine except if i run this for a 3X3 matrix it doesnt output the last number but i think ur code fixes that issue then teacher that i am studying from wrote the same code as u but well in general i use less while loops so i went with for loop works fine for everything except this 3X3 matrix so i feel its a trade off kinda dont know if u can fix this or not do tell if u have found any solution to this

edit :- i know that i have used extra variables

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int array2d1[][] = new int[a][b];
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                array2d1[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        int b1 = 0;
        int b2 = 0;
        int x = a;
        int j = 0;
        int y = b;
        for(int g=0;g<=a/2;g++) {

            for (j = b1; j <=y; j++) {
                if (j < y - 1) {
                    System.out.print(array2d1[i][j]);
                }
//            else if(j==y-1){
//                j=y-1;
//            }

            }
            j = y - 1;
            y --;
            x --;
            for (i = b2; i < x; i++) {
                if (i < x) {
                    System.out.print(array2d1[i][j]);
                }
            }
            b2++;
            i = x;
            for (j = y; j > b1; j--) {
                if (j > b1) {
                    System.out.print(array2d1[i][j]);
                }
            }
            for (i = x; i >= b2; i--) {
                System.out.print(array2d1[i][j]);

            }
            b1++;
            i=b2;

        }
//        System.out.println(i);
//        System.out.println(j);
//        System.out.println(y);




    }

}
```